# Understanding the Agent Blowfish random event

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

At random intervals a hacker by the name "Agent Blowfish" sends you "encrypted" messages. You then have to "decrypt" the message, and the actual message is displayed. It looks like base64, but I'm not positive. Also, what does it actually do if you pay him?

**Is the "encrypted" message base64, and what are the outcomes of paying for his "services"?**

Comment: What about... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher) ?

Comment: +1 for discovering the reason for the name, but I think the messages are in base64... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have so far seen two possible outcomes as a result of paying for his services;

Unlocking research, this is normally a "new topic", for money instead of research points. This is presented to you as "getting hold of new technology" or "borrowing technology".

Sabotaging your competitors, this usually costs more and results in the development that one of your competitors is doing getting sabotaged.

Comment: So you either "steal" a new topic or slow the development of a competitor? Does sabotaging a competitor just increase the attention your game gets?

Comment: While it's not explicitly mentioned in the game, I would suspect that it improves your sales due to your competitors not releasing a game at the same time as you.